# Searching files in C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, file

How  would one search for files on a computer?
Maybe looking for certain extensions.

I need to iterate through all the files and examine file names.

Say I wanted to find all files with an .code extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse through"?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, you would want to look into the [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) and [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx) functions. If you want to implement a recursive search, you can use GetFileAttributes() to check for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`. If the file is actually a directory, continue into it with your search.

Comment: FindFirst/NextFile will already tell you the attributes of the file; not need to call GetFileAttributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FindFirstFile()` or `FindNextFile()` functions and a recursive algorithm to traverse sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

A nice wrapper for FindFirstFile is dirent.h for windows (google dirent.h Toni Ronkko)

```
#define S_ISREG(B) ((B)&_S_IFREG)
#define S_ISDIR(B) ((B)&_S_IFDIR)

static void
scan_dir(DirScan *d, const char *adir, BOOL recurse_dir)
{
    DIR *dirfile;
    int adir_len = strlen(adir);

    if ((dirfile = opendir(adir)) != NULL) {
        struct dirent *entry;
        char    path[MAX_PATH + 1];
        char    *file;

        while ((entry = readdir(dirfile)) != NULL)
        { 
            struct stat buf;
            if(!strcmp(".",entry->d_name) || !strcmp("..",entry->d_name))
                continue;

            sprintf(path,"%s/%.*s", adir, MAX_PATH-2-adir_len, entry->d_name);

            if (stat(path,&buf) != 0)
                continue;

            file = entry->d_name;
            if (recurse_dir && S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) )
                scan_dir(d, path, recurse_dir);
            else if (match_extension(path) && _access(path, R_OK) == 0) // e.g. match .code
                strs_find_add_str(&d->files,&d->n_files,_strdup(path));
        }
        closedir(dirfile);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

FindFirstFile()/ FindNextFile() will do the job in finding the list of files in the directory. To do recursive search through the sub-directories you might use [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf(VS.80).aspx)

to split the path, into directory and filenames, and then use the resulting directory detail to do a recursive directory search.